# Hide custom UI element in extended XML file in custom theme

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, xml, uicomponent

This is original file in `code` dir of a third part module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Amasty\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Head" name="amasty.checkout.head"  template="Amasty_Checkout::onepage/head.phtml" after="-"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Amasty_Checkout/js/view/onepage</item>
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">sidebar</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Amasty_Checkout/onepage/sidebar-summary</item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="additional" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Amasty_Checkout/js/view/additional/fieldset</item>
                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="subscribe" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Amasty_Checkout/js/view/additional/subscribe</item>
                                                    <item name="description" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sign Up for Our Newsletter</item>
                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">amcheckout.additional.subscribe</item>
                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                    <item name="checked" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I want to hide the element but extending the XML layout file in my custom theme. This is my extended XML file, however, I can't get it to work... Element is still visible on the frontend.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Amasty_Checkout/js/view/onepage</item>
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="additional" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="subscribe" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Is it even possible to hide the element by extending the XML file or do I have to create a custom module and set up a preference for it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for how to disable a component rather that make it invisible, if you want it to function but not be visible use `opacity: 0;` or `visibility: hidden;` in CSS.

**How to disable a component**
Instructions taken from the [dev docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html):

```
<item name="%the_component_to_be_disabled%" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

So in your case:

```
...
    <item name="subscribe" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
...
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to disable the functionality of the element, but also, don't want to keep it in the DOM for no reason. I moved the element in the extended XML file and I want to remove the redundant one. I guess this cannot be achieved then can it?